# domain of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}{n^x + |x|^n} $

Tags: calculus

I've been sitting on this one for a while now and still not able to find the domain of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}{n^x + |x|^n} $ .

The answer i've reached is that $ \frac{-1}{2}< x < \frac{1}{2} $ but its not the right answer apparently. Not quite sure how to check for negative numbers specifically as well.

I've used $\lim|\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}| < 1 $  for that.

Any advice would help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by radius of convergence in this context? This is not a power series.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Im not a native speaker so im not sure how to translate it, maybe range of convergence?

Comment: I think that “domain of convergence” would be a better choice.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks, updated to that

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}{n^x + |x|^n} $
This converges for any $x>0$ using the alternating series test since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2^n}}{n^x + |x|^n} = 0$